# Flask app submit target="_blank" form only after wtforms validation

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

In my Flask app I have a form generated with `wtforms` and `jinja` templates. If validation passes I want to redirect in a new tab, else I want to stay on the same page and display the errors. However if I set `target="_blank"` in my form, it opens a new tab without validation passing and shows the errors there. Removing `target="_blank"` will not open a new tab. Is there a way of achieving this without rewriting the whole validation in js? Thanks!

Code:

```
from wtforms import Form, TextAreaField, StringField, validators

class SubmitForm(Form):
    field1 = StringField(u'field1', [validators.DataRequired()])
    field2 = TextAreaField(u'field2', [validators.DataRequired()])

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def sub():
    form = SubmitForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        # great success
        return redirect('/my_redirect_uri')
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

@app.route('/')
def layout():
    return render_template('index.html', form=SubmitForm())
```

**index.html:**

```
{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form method=post action="/" target="_blank">
  <dl>
    {{ render_field(form.field1) }}
    {{ render_field(form.field2) }}
  </dl>
  <p><input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

**_formhelpers.html**(not that relevant but for the sake of completness):

```
{% macro render_field(field) %}
  <dt>{{ field.label }}
  <dd>{{ field(**kwargs)|safe }}
  {% if field.errors %}
    <ul class=errors>
    {% for error in field.errors %}
      <li>{{ error }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
  </dd>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: I guess you're right. You need to write a simple controller that validates your Ajax request and after that you can open new tab,

Answer (score 3):

## Main issue

You must pass the `form` object as well as the variables representing your form fields namely `field1` and `field2`.

## Details

What is being stated above means that you need to change:

`return redirect('/my_redirect_uri')`

to

`return redirect('/my_redirect_uri', form=form, field1=field1, field2=field2)`

This also means that you have to adjustments to your view method:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def sub():
    form = SubmitForm(request.form)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        # great success
        field1 = form.field1.data
        field2 = form.field2.data
        return redirect('/my_redirect_uri', form=form, field1=field1, field2=field2)
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```

Now there are some improvements to your program:

- Code less principle:

Replace `if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():` by `if form.validate_on_submit():` (you save one instruction)

- Use [`url_for()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.url_for):

For the sake of [scalability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) because in future versions and reedits of your program, any changes made to route names will be automatically available when using `url_for()` as it generates URLs using the URL map. You may use it in `return redirect('/my_redirect_uri')` (you may check the link I provided for further information)

- Use sessions:

Sessions will make your application "able to remember" the form data being sent. In your example, you can use a session this way:

```
session['field1'] = form.field1.data
session['field2'] = form.field2.data
```

This means, for example, the above line:

```
return redirect('/my_redirect_uri', form=form, field1=field1, field2=field2)
```

must be changed to:

```
return redirect('my_redirect_uri', form=form, session.get('field1'), session.get('field2'))
```

Note that if you want to implement sessions, you will need to set a secret key because they are stored on the client side, so they need to be protected (cryptographically in Flask's philosophy). This mean you must configure your application this way:

```
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some secret phrase of your own'
```

Actually, the problem is not related to the browser tab you opened. The whole issue emanates from the `redirect()` statement.

More details on why it is good to use sessions? Check the next last section:

## A word about redirect:

Your POST request is handled by  `redirect`, consequently you loose access to the form data when the POST request ends.

The redirect statement is simply a response which, when received, the browser issues a GET request. This mechanism is there mainly for the following (and similar) situation:

If you try to refresh the same browser window on which you submitted the form data, the browser will prompt you a pop up window to confirm  that you want to send the data (again) because the browser remembers, by design, the last request it performed. Of course, this is nasty for the user of your application. There we need sessions. This is also helpful for the browser tab to which you redirect.

Comment: Tried this. In cases of errors a new tab still opens with the errored form. It's better than nothing but if one wants the errors to show in the previous tab one has to do js validation.