# Unable to grab posted form info using flask-wtf-forms

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, wtforms, flask-wtforms

[image]

I'm trying to extend the flask-base project http://hack4impact.github.io/flask-base/templates/ . I have the following view functions:

```
@login_required
@main.route('/cities', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def cities():
    if request.method =='POST':
        print(request.data)
        redirect('/selected')


    cities_list = []

    recordset = Postings.query.all()
    for r in recordset:
        city = str(r.city)
        elapsed_hours = round((time.time() - int(r.datetime)) / 3600, 1)
        cities_list.append(str(r.city) + '-' + str(r.email) + '-' + str(elapsed_hours))

    form = PostingSelectForm()
    form.posting.choices = [(item, item) for item in cities_list]


    return render_template("main/cities.html",
                           form = form)

@login_required
@main.route('/selected')
def selected():
    return 'ddd'
```

I'm using a macro to generate a form as described in the docs above. The macro is called render_template and works normally to produce a form which I am able to submit. You can see the submitted info in the screenshot. However I am not able to capture the info in the lines:

```
        print(request.data)
        redirect('/selected')
```

and the redirect does not occur. When I look at the html of the wtf-form generated by the macro. it starts with;

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="" class="ui form 
    ">
<div style="display:none;"><input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="1516882441##491001e55a57ceac4053b7937d21e61768f66d0b"></div>
```

So I'm wondering if the lack of an action is the problem here. I don't know what posting to "" does. Also if that is the problem how would I modify my form to include an action given that is generated by this macro. My forms code is:

```
class PostingSelectForm(Form):

    posting = SelectField(
        'posting',
        choices=[('cpp', 'C++'), ('py', 'Python'), ('text', 'Plain Text')]
    )
    submit = SubmitField('Select')
```

Comment: https://pybit.es/flask-sessions.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40817966/flask-app-submit-target-blank-form-only-after-wtforms-validation